# Why don't hidden field targets need to be attributes of the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm working on a rails project and I've come across something that seems strange. I have a form in my view, and for any normal field such as `f.text_field` if the model doesn't have the required attribute, I get an error, for example:

```
f.text_field :thing_that_doesnt_exist
```

gives me the error:

```
undefined method `thing_that_doesnt_exist' for #<Model:0x007f7d00b809a0>
```

However:

```
f.hidden_field :thing_that_doesnt_exist
```

doesn't give me an error and I'm not sure why, surely it should work the same way as the text field. If anyone can help me understand what's going on here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show the full error message ?

Comment: in your model put attr_accessor :thing_that_doesnt_exist

Comment: I understand that, as I stated in my question, my confusion comes from the fact that `f.hidden_field :thing_that_doesnt_exist` doesn't give the same error.

Comment: Excellent question - I'm totally perplexed after looking at [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/46c2e93051ab33157c584292a2743f9482e99582/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1193). Its defined as `Tags::HiddenField.new(object_name, method, self, options).render`. The thing is that `Tags::HiddenField` is just subclass of `Tags::TextField` so they get the value from the object in the [exact same way](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9c35bf2a6a27431c6aa283db781c19f61c5155be/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_field.rb#L15).

Comment: Yep, the should both give errors or both not, they have to get a value from the model regardless... Are they in the same form?

Comment: Yup the same form, the only difference is the hidden field has a `value:` param

Comment: Where is the `value` in your example?

Answer (score 1):

**Case1: Works without error**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :thing_that_doesnt_exist, :value => "x" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'thing_that_doesnt_exist', "x" %>
```

**Case2: Throws error if value not mentioned(as it will try to call attribute name which is not present)**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :thing_that_doesnt_exist%>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'thing_that_doesnt_exist'%>
```

**Case3: Works for existing field thing_that_does_exist**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :thing_that_does_exist%>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'thing_that_does_exist'%>
```

Comment: Good catch that the example was flawed.